# What is the use of "?" in typescript when used after a variable

Tags: typescript

what is "?" in  "instances?.map" doing here. I thought it was checking for instances to be non-null before executing map on it. If it is what might be the reason for this error?
[image]

Comment: See: [Optional Chaining](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj6-ubx99HzAhWRsRQKHSM8AhAQFnoECAUQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen-US%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FOperators%2FOptional_chaining&usg=AOvVaw3fLcEvZqB0O4DQx47AqDMT)

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of  `.?` is correct.

(With code like`x.y` you call `.` the "chaining operator".

With `x?.y` you call `?.` the "optinal chaining operator" meaning that if `x` is nullish it will bail and not run the map fn)

**The error is unrelated to the optional chaining**.
you would've got the same error if you used normal chaining.
The error is likely that `instances` is NOT actually an Array so lacks the `map` function.

`instances` might be some kind of "Array-like object".

(Like a list of Promises.
Or a NodeList.
For example: `document.querySelectorAll("a")` returns a NodeList which is ...kinda lika an array but not exactly, it lacks a map function. So you need to convert it to an Array first if you wanna map.

Example:
This throws an error because the return object lacks a map fn: `document.querySelectorAll("a").map(link => link.innerHTML)`

This works because the return object has a map fn:
`Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("a")).map(link => link.innerHTML)`

Answer (score 0):

The error does **not** say that `instances` is null, it says that it does not have a `.map` function.

You should check where it is declared and what it contains. It looks like an object, you cannot use `.map` on an object like that but it has to be an array.